# ServiceTracker vs BundleTracker

Tags: java, osgi

The OSGi enterprise specification defines two ways of tracking: by service or by bundle.

What are the differences between these two ways? In which cases, one way should be used over another?

Thanks

Comment: The clue is in the name. It just depends what you want to track ;-)

Comment: @NeilBartlett Ok, so I understand that more than one service may be defined by a bundle?

Comment: Bundles publish zero to many services. Really you should not look at either of these utilities at this stage. You should focus on a simple way to work with services, I recommend Declarative Services. I also recommend getting a book like "OSGi in Action" rather than trying to plough through the specs.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? A servicetracker may be a solution but without a problem it is difficult to say if it is a good one :-)

Comment: @NeilBartlett: Or how about "OSGi in Practice". :-) http://njbartlett.name/osgibook.html

Comment: @ChrisDolan Nah that's a terrible book and the author is a moron. He didn't even finish it, and it doesn't cover `BundleTracker` anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you are willing to track.

The BundleTracker tracks bundles, see:

- http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/BundleTracker.html
- http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/BundleTrackerCustomizer.html

And the ServiceTracker tracks service instances, see:

- http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/ServiceTracker.html
- http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/ServiceTrackerCustomizer.html

So obviously if you are interested in what happens with bundles, you use the BundleTracker. And if you are interested in service instances, you use the ServiceTracker.

Answer (score 0):

To put it very simply: 
The bundle is the jar. You can track whether it is installed, successfully started, not yet started etc.

A bundle can publish zero or more services. A service in OSGi terms is the live java object which provides you methods for doing something. Even if the bundle is there, its services could have disappeared (e.g. because the bundle is stopped; or is installed but not yet started). Even if the bundle is in the ACTIVE state, it could still be waiting for some condition in order to provide its services - it depends fully on the bundle decision when it registers and unregisters its services.

In the most typical case your code works with services - e.g. you get the LogService and call its log() method. So in 99% of the cases you should be interested in the ServiceListener (or, even better, use the ServiceTracker instead, it does the same, but takes care of some typical synchronization pitfalls for you).

Hope this helps :)